# Changing Win64 attribute of component in custom action

Tags: outlook, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to add the registry value for outlookaddin . Since the registry destination is determined by the outlook architecture/bitness, I need to set the component ***component Win64 attribute*** on the basis of ***outlook's architecture*** and I have a custom action to determine it's architecture.

Here is the fragment of the wix

```
  <Component Id="Registry" Guid="446A9B40-1C57-4D51-BF81-4EAD54A44BD7" Directory="OutLookAddInFolder" Win64="no" ><!--Set the value of Win64 on the basis of outlook bitness-->
    <RegistryKey  Root="HKMU" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddIn"  ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes" >
      <RegistryValue Name="FriendlyName" Action="write" Value="Name" Type="string" KeyPath="yes"   />
      <RegistryValue Name="Description" Action="write" Value="Description" Type="string" KeyPath="no" />
      <RegistryValue Name="LoadBehavior" Action="write" Value="3" Type="integer" KeyPath="no" />
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

Is there a way to do this in custom action or somehow during installation process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience the normal way to do this is just to have two copies of the component, one 64 bit and one 32-bit (different ids obviously), and give each one a condition, one the opposite of the other. You don't say how you're deciding on the bitness, but I've seen people do registry searches and component searches for Office information, using that to set the property.

By definition you must be building a 64-bit MSI (because 32-bit MSIs must contain only 32-bit components):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

so if you want a single MSI to support both then having both choices available and conditioned works ok, and there's probably no need for any code or custom actions if a search finds your 64-bit Outlook item.

Comment: I am building 32 bit MSI and the way I am checking the image type of outlook.exe to determine its bitness in Customaction. Anyways the conditional feature works fine for 64 bit registry manipulation from 32 bit msi. Thanks!!!